# How to get the value of a string in a case statement in elm

Tags: elm

Consider the following. Why does it not work. And how could I make it work?

```elm
type IntOrString
  = String
  | Int

getInt : IntOrString -> String
getInt intOrString =
  case intOrString of
    String ->
      intOrString

    Int ->
      toString intOrString
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your declaration of the `IntOrString` type seems to indicate that you want a type that can hold either an integer or a string. However, that's not what you have created. I recommend reading the [section on Union Types](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html) in the Elm Guide.

When you declare a union type, you have to create constructors. In your example, you're actually creating a type with two constructors, neither of which contain a parameter, so although you call them `Int` and `String`, they bear no relationship to Elm's native `Int` and `String` types. In this case, they can be considered roughly equivalent to an enum inside a language like C# or Java.

Furthermore, your declaration causes compiler confusion because you have created constructor names that clash with existing types, so elsewhere in your code the compiler gets confused by which thing you mean when you say `Int` or `String`.

Let's redefine the type so that it becomes a single type that can hold an integer or string value. I'll also rename the constructors to avoid name collisions.

```elm
type IntOrString
  = MyString String
  | MyInt Int
```

And now you can tweak the `getInt` function based on the new definition. Notice how pattern matching is used to pull the string or integer value out of the `IntOrString` value based on which constructor was used to create it:

```elm
getInt : IntOrString -> String
getInt intOrString =
  case intOrString of
    MyString s ->
      s

    MyInt i ->
      toString i
```

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for clarifying. I was thinking of Union types in languages like typescript where you can combine with any built in type. but that is something different with a same name.